# Combining two JSON into one using Python

Tags: python, json

I have two JSON, I want to combine into one.

**JSON 1**

```
[ 
   { 
      "city":"Aberdeen",
      "year":1996,
      "occupancy_change":null,
      "effective_rent_change":null
   },
   { 
      "city":"Aberdeen",
      "year":1997,
      "occupancy_change":null,
      "effective_rent_change":null
   },
   { 
      "city":"Ambler",
      "year":1996,
      "occupancy_change":1.65,
      "effective_rent_change":4.37
   },
   { 
      "city":"Ambler",
      "year":1997,
      "occupancy_change":1.17,
      "effective_rent_change":-0.25
   }
]
```

**JSON 2**

```
[ 
   { 
      "year":1996,
      "pma_occupancy_change":null,
      "pma_effective_rent_change":null
   },
   { 
      "year":1997,
      "pma_occupancy_change":null,
      "pma_effective_rent_change":null
   }
]
```

I want to combine two json into one, I want to get into the format below.

```
[ 
   { 
      "year":1996,
      "pma_occupancy_change":null,
      "pma_effective_rent_change":null,
      "city":"Aberdeen",
      "occupancy_change":null,
      "effective_rent_change":null,
      "city":"Ambler",
      "occupancy_change":1.65,
      "effective_rent_change":4.37
   },
   { 
      "year":1997,
      "pma_occupancy_change":null,
      "pma_effective_rent_change":null,
      "city":"Aberdeen",
      "occupancy_change":null,
      "effective_rent_change":null
      "city":"Ambler",
      "occupancy_change":1.17,
      "effective_rent_change":-0.25
   }
]
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but it didn't work for me.

```
from collections import defaultdict

null = None    
d = defaultdict(dict)

for l in (city_li, pma_li):
   for elem in l:
       d[elem['year']].update(elem)

l3 = d.values()
print l3
```

Comment: You have duplicate keys. A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: As @LucaCappelletti mentioned, the output you are expecting is not possible. 'city', 'occupancy_change' and 'effective_rent_change' are repeated in the dict.

Comment: Duplicate keys? That's collision right there !

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid json.

Comment: Duplicate keys will be merged into one. so, your desired output may not be generated.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void concat2JSONStrings() {
            String JSONString1 = "[ \r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Aberdeen\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1996,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Aberdeen\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1997,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Ambler\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1996,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":1.65,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":4.37\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Ambler\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1997,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":1.17,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":-0.25\r\n" + 
                    "   }\r\n" + 
                    "]";

            String JSONString2 = "[ \r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1996,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1997,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   }\r\n" + 
                    "]";

            JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(JSONString1);
            JsonPath jp1 = new JsonPath(JSONString2);
            System.out.println(jp.get("city[0]").toString());
            System.out.println(jp1.get("year[0]").toString());

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("year", jp.get("city[0]"));
            json.put("pma_occupancy_change", jp1.get("pma_occupancy_change[0]"));


Once you have the JSONObject then you can convert to JSONArray and meet your output.
```

Comment: Can you help me in Python

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Java using simple JSON:

```
        @Test
        public void concat2JSONStrings() {
            String JSONString1 = "[ \r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Aberdeen\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1996,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Aberdeen\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1997,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Ambler\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1996,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":1.65,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":4.37\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"city\":\"Ambler\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1997,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"occupancy_change\":1.17,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"effective_rent_change\":-0.25\r\n" + 
                    "   }\r\n" + 
                    "]";

            String JSONString2 = "[ \r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1996,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   },\r\n" + 
                    "   { \r\n" + 
                    "      \"year\":1997,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_occupancy_change\":null,\r\n" + 
                    "      \"pma_effective_rent_change\":null\r\n" + 
                    "   }\r\n" + 
                    "]";

            JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(JSONString1);
            JsonPath jp1 = new JsonPath(JSONString2);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("year", jp.get("city[0]"));
            json.put("pma_occupancy_change", jp1.get("pma_occupancy_change[0]"));
            json.put("pma_effective_rent_change", jp1.get("pma_effective_rent_change[0]"));
            json.put("city",jp.get("city[0]"));
            json.put("occupancy_change",jp.get("occupancy_change[0]"));
            json.put("effective_rent_change",jp.get("effective_rent_change[0]"));
            json.put("city",jp.get("city[2]"));
            json.put("occupancy_change",jp.get("occupancy_change[2]"));
            json.put("effective_rent_change",jp.get("effective_rent_change[2]"));

            JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
            json1.put("year", jp.get("city[2]"));
            json1.put("pma_occupancy_change", jp1.get("pma_occupancy_change[0]"));
            json1.put("pma_effective_rent_change", jp1.get("pma_effective_rent_change[0]"));
            json1.put("city",jp.get("city[0]"));
            json1.put("occupancy_change",jp.get("occupancy_change[0]"));
            json1.put("effective_rent_change",jp.get("effective_rent_change[0]"));
            json1.put("city",jp.get("city[2]"));
            json1.put("occupancy_change",jp.get("occupancy_change[3]"));
            json1.put("effective_rent_change",jp.get("effective_rent_change[3]"));

            JSONArray ja1 = new JSONArray();
            ja1.add(json);
            ja1.add(json1);
            System.out.println("Required appended JSON Output is: "+ja1.toJSONString());





        }
```

Desired Output:

Required appended JSON output is:

> [{"effective_rent_change":4.37,"year":"Aberdeen","city":"Ambler","pma_effective_rent_change":null,"pma_occupancy_change":null,"occupancy_change":1.65},{"effective_rent_change":-0.25,"year":"Ambler","city":"Ambler","pma_effective_rent_change":null,"pma_occupancy_change":null,"occupancy_change":1.17}]

Comment: amend the key values as i might have mistaken some of them. please let me know if this is of any use to you.

Comment: please look at the comments already mentioned about others on duplicates in JSON string

Answer (score -2):

Concat the two strings.

```
@Test
    public void concat2JSONStrings() {
        String JSONString1 = "\"[ \r\n" + 
                "   { \r\n" + 
                "      \\\"city\\\":\\\"Aberdeen\\\",\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"year\\\":1996,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"occupancy_change\\\":null,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"effective_rent_change\\\":null\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   { \r\n" + 
                "      \\\"city\\\":\\\"Aberdeen\\\",\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"year\\\":1997,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"occupancy_change\\\":null,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"effective_rent_change\\\":null\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   { \r\n" + 
                "      \\\"city\\\":\\\"Ambler\\\",\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"year\\\":1996,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"occupancy_change\\\":1.65,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"effective_rent_change\\\":4.37\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   { \r\n" + 
                "      \\\"city\\\":\\\"Ambler\\\",\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"year\\\":1997,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"occupancy_change\\\":1.17,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"effective_rent_change\\\":-0.25\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "]\""; 

        String JSONString2 = "\"[ \r\n" + 
                "   { \r\n" + 
                "      \\\"year\\\":1996,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"pma_occupancy_change\\\":null,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"pma_effective_rent_change\\\":null\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   { \r\n" + 
                "      \\\"year\\\":1997,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"pma_occupancy_change\\\":null,\r\n" + 
                "      \\\"pma_effective_rent_change\\\":null\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "]\"";

        System.out.println(JSONString1.concat(JSONString2));

    }
```

Output:

```
"[ 
   { 
      \"city\":\"Aberdeen\",
      \"year\":1996,
      \"occupancy_change\":null,
      \"effective_rent_change\":null
   },
   { 
      \"city\":\"Aberdeen\",
      \"year\":1997,
      \"occupancy_change\":null,
      \"effective_rent_change\":null
   },
   { 
      \"city\":\"Ambler\",
      \"year\":1996,
      \"occupancy_change\":1.65,
      \"effective_rent_change\":4.37
   },
   { 
      \"city\":\"Ambler\",
      \"year\":1997,
      \"occupancy_change\":1.17,
      \"effective_rent_change\":-0.25
   }
]""[ 
   { 
      \"year\":1996,
      \"pma_occupancy_change\":null,
      \"pma_effective_rent_change\":null
   },
   { 
      \"year\":1997,
      \"pma_occupancy_change\":null,
      \"pma_effective_rent_change\":null
   }
]"
```

Comment: I can see from your question, you actually want to append the array string is it??? my bad i did not read it properly.

Comment: Use JSONPATH and parse the 2 strings as per your requirement. Once done, then convert it to a new string.

Comment: can you help in python